# Insertar registros c# con mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

Tengo la necesidad de insertar valores en mysql, el desarrollo es en c# y aún no encuentro como poder ejecutar alguna interacción con la BD.

el código es el siguiente:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();

try
{                                        
     conn.ConnectionString = cs;
     conn.Open();
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
     cmd.Connection = conn;

     cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `prueba`.`facturas` (`Version`) VALUES ('3.3')";
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
     if (conn != null)
     {
          conn.Close();
     }
}
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Que problema tienes con el código que muestras? Tienes conocimientos de sql?

Comment: el código debería insertar valores en la base de dato, pero cuando lo ejecuto no hace nada y tampoco genera error.

Comment: Vamos paso a paso. En que parte del código estás indicando los valores a insertar en la base de datos? Por otro lado..tienes algun procedimiento almacenado en la bbdd para insertar datos?

Comment: Los valores los obtengo de un xml y los almaceno en variables, en el código de arriba no tengo esas variables  solo quiero ver como poder guardar y después hacer los ajustes, en cuanto a la segunda pregunta, no tengo procedimientos almacenados en la bd

Comment: El insert que estás utilizando no es un query sql válido. Revisa [insert](https://www.1keydata.com/es/sql/sql-insert-into.php). Por otro lado, si quieres usar un query sql, la linea `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` sobra, esta es solo para llamadas a procedimientos almacenados

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a revisar

Comment: También te falta algo muy importante: no estás ejecutando la query. Necesitas abrir la conexion, ejecutar `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` y cerrar la conexion. Revisa el ejemplo de Insert que tienes en [esta página](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ExecuteNonQuery-Insert-Update-and-Delete-examples-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx), es la forma correcta de ejecutar una query (ten en cuenta que debes usar `MySqlConnection` en lugar de `SqlConnection` y asi en todo)

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso era lo que faltaba, ejecutar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomiendo restructurar el codigo de la siguiente forma

```
try
{                                        
    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cs))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string query = "INSERT INTO `prueba`.`facturas` (`Version`) VALUES ('3.3')";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

- No necesitas cerrar la conexion si la defines dentro del `using`
- Para ejecutar usa el `ExecuteNonQuery()`